# Angular 2: Nested templates with ngTemplateOutlet and ngOutletContext

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to build a generic list component using PrimeNG's p-dataScroller like this:

```
<div>
  <p-dataScroller [value]="items" ...more properties...>
    <template let-listItem>
      <div (click)="select(listItem)">
        <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate"
                  [ngOutletContext]="{'item': listItem, 'selected': listItem == selectedItem}"></template>
      </div>
    </template>
  </p-dataScroller>
</div>
```

p-dataScroller itself uses a template to propagate each item in the `items` array.
`selectedItem` and `select()` are methods of the corresponding generic-list component. In this component I am declaring `itemTemplate` like this:

```
 @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
 public itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

And finally I am using my generic list component in the following way:

```
<generic-list [items]="someArray">
  <template>
    <list-item [itemType]="itemType">
      <template let-item>
        <i class ="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-lock': item.visibility == 0,
                                   'fa-users': item.visibility == 1}"></i>
      </template>
    </list-item>
  </template>
</generic-list>
```

As you can see, the template component (`list-item`) itself has another template!
First of all I would like to know if this poses a problem (three nested templates) but more importantly, the values in `ngOutletContext` do not seem to be added to each `list-item`. Both, `item` and `selected` input parameters exist in the list-item component, but they don't seem to be set. When debugging, Angular 2 adds the list-item component correctly as a list entry but throws an exception because it is missing the `item` input parameter in `AfterContentInit`. Interestingly, the `itemType` input parameter is being set correctly, probably because it is not part of `ngOutletContext`.

I can't move the list-item component inside the generic-list component template, reducing complexity, since there are several different types of items that can be used (all of which would have `item`, `selected` etc).

**How can I set `@Input()` parameters for a template correctly using values from inside another template?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was all correct except for

```
<generic-list [items]="someArray">
  <!-- had to declare the 'ngOutletContext' values here!! -->
  <template let-item="item" let-selected="selected">
    <!-- makes using it here easy -->
    <list-item [item]="item" [selected]="selected" [itemType]="itemType">
      <template>
        ...
      </template>
    </list-item>
  </template>
</generic-list>
```

This was really hard to find. Could not find any documentation on this topic.

Comment: Please note that since Angular 4 `template` is now called `ng-template`.

Comment: Nice answer. I also found it considerably more difficult than usual to find documentation on this topic.